# recaptcha v3 form not submiting

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Im trying to avoid recaptcha v3 timeout by delaying execution until it is submited. Sadly the submit button does nothing when I press it. Here is my code.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      grecaptcha.execute('xxxxxx', {
        action: 'homepage'
      }).then(function(token) {
        var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
        recaptchaResponse.value = token;
        document.getElementById('contactForm').submit();
      });
    }, false);

  });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="<? echo $url . '/nueva/'; ?>" id="contactForm">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-3 col-form-label" for="palabra">address</label>
    <div class="col-9">
      <input id="address" name="address" type="text" class="form-control here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-3 col-9">
      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Enviar</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it's php & javascript,
My code is ASP.NET MVC & JQuery, but you can try that

Javascript

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                grecaptcha.execute('xxxxxx', { action: 'homepage' }).then(function (token) {
                    var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
                    recaptchaResponse.value = token;
                });
            });
        });
    }, false);

});
```

HTML

```
<button id="enviar" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Enviar</button>
```